# Is there a standard in REST to define if response related entities must be resolved as objects or be lazy hyperlinks?

Tags: rest

I want to provide to my REST clients a mechanism to define if response related entities must be resolved as objects or be lazy hyperlinks.

This is a normal json output:

```
{
  "userName" : "jhon",i
  ...
  "lastPurchasedBooks" : [ { "ISBN":"12345", "Title":"Abc", ...}, ...]
}
```

and this is the lazy option:

```
{
  "userName" : "jhon",
  ...
  "lastPurchasedBooks" : [ "http://xxx/books/12345", ...]
}
```

I'm thinking on solutions as define this as a content negotiation (different accept headers values, specific url, etc)

There is a "standard" to define this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of your custom media-type; that is how the semantics of the data are conveyed to the requester.

If your custom media-type (say `application/json+booklist`) is defined as having a list of book entities, then I guess it might be fine,

However, I am inclined to go with the latter, as that is the "typical" REST way (i.e., what you have identified as the "lazy" way). So in that case, you'd have a custom media-type called `application/json+book` which defines what a JSON response for a `Book` entity would look like. Correspondingly, your custom media-type `application/json+booklist` will be modified to contain a list of links to `Book` entities instead of having a list of actual `Book` entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your question screams for a hypermedia format like [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language) or [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren).

In HAL you can express relationships via links, but if you want to *also* include a full object representation you can include the entire object in `_embedded`.

Objects in `_embedded` still have a URI themselves.